# UNIX egrep multiple strings

Tags: unix

I am attempting to search multiple files within a directory, using multiple egrep pipes I am organize the data I need, but it matches every single line.  I am only need it to match one line, and continue to the next file in the directory.

Ex:

```
egrep -i "stringname" * | egrep -i "anotherstringname"
```

Is there another way? Any recommendations, I am new to Unix.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
egrep -m 1 "string1|string2|string3" *.txt
```

(where I assume your files have names matching *.txt). For instance, on my own computer if I type:

```
egrep -m 1 "def|append" *.py
```

I will search at most 1 line in each python file matching either "def" or "append".